# How do I interprete the database diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, model, diagram, relationship

I am new to database and I saw some database diagram with

- has[1:0-N],
- is[1:0-N],
- has from[1:1],
- has to[1:1]

labeled next to the linkages between the "boxes". Where can I find out more on what each of the above means?

For a database diagram to have the above "labels", what is the diagram called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be talking about an Entity Relationship Model.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model

As far as the relationships you're talking about, those should be representing how different tables relate to each other, such as:

`Table A is Table B`
`Table A has N references to Table B`
`Table A has a foreign key to/from Table B`

Answer (score 0):

These are basically the relationships in RDBMS(databases) and 1:0-N means 1 value of an attribute of one table has many relations with many values of another table attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

These labels refer to [Cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29), which describes the number of rows in one table that another row in another table is related to.